# Is this way of ISSET validity a correct PHP practice?

Tags: php, kohana

Instead of:

```
<?php echo isset($an_array['array_key']) ? $an_array['array_key'] : ''; ?>
```

I found out that I can go with only:

```
<?php echo $an_array['array_key'] ?: ''; ?>
```

This eliminates (isset) so I wonder if this is a good way of coding or a bad way of coding?

(I am just learning PHP)

Comment: I prefer the first way - The second will raise a notice if the key is not set. Not to mention that your second way will not output anything, because there is nothing between the question mark and colon.

Comment: @nickb: it is the short way of writing of ternary operator in php 5.3, and it will output a variable if it is not empty

Comment: note that isset returns true on null values, thus $an_array['array_key'] that contains a null value will return false which is not necessarily what you want. Consider using array_key_exists instead...

Answer (score 3):

The second one would lead to notice of undefined variable or undefined index. So the only correct way to do it is the first one.

<strike>If you have your notices turned off - then your second code is absolutely the same as:</strike>

```
<?php echo $an_array['array_key']; ?>
```

BTW, as long as you use Kohana3 you could use:

```
<?php echo Arr::get($an_array, 'array_key', 'default value'); ?>
```

But only in cases if you're sure that `$an_array` variable is defined

Comment: If `$an_array['array_key']='0'`, the code would not be the same

Answer (score 2):

I am against the use of the `?:` operator, because it is a source of "oops" bugs. Anything that evaluates to false will not be printed. Check these out:

```
$an_array['array_key'] = 0;
echo $an_array['array_key'] ?: '!!!';

$an_array['array_key'] = '0';
echo $an_array['array_key'] ?: '!!!';

$an_array['array_key'] = false;
echo $an_array['array_key'] ?: '!!!';

// ok, this is not the best example, but literally anything
// that evaluates to false can cause a problem:
$an_array['array_key'] = array(); 
echo $an_array['array_key'] ?: '!!!';
```

In all the above examples, the `isset` would have returned `true`.

Comment: Agree with any example but not the latest - there is no reason ever to echo arrays

Comment: @zerkms, yes, it's a bad example in this case. In any case, my point is that you have to double think before using this operator.

Answer (score 1):

The second example may generate a *undefined variable notice* if `$an_array['array_key']` was never set

Comment: Also, if you're new to PHP I would advice you to have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 1):

It will ultimately depend on what you are trying to do but if `$an_array['array_key']` was equal to zero, the 2nd method would echo empty string

If you wanted to check if the key exists, even if it's null.  Use `array_key_exists`

If you wanted to check if the variable is not null. Use `isset`

If nothing is used like in the 2nd example you gave, it will be converted to boolean: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: http://nz.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary see the "Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out ..." paragraph